# Passing OpenCv Mat Object From Java to C Native

Tags: java, c, opencv, java-native-interface

I'm trying to read an image by opencv then pass it from java language to my native library written by C Language not C++.
I'm using JNI function and I've seen many samples of c++ code in which Mat Object is used.
but my problem is that there isn't any Mat object in "C Language" and the only object I have is CvMat.So when I get my image in my native codes it is a wrong image.
I should mention that I can not use c++ for many reasons and the C is my only option to write native code.

My Java Code:

```
Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread("./mypic.jpg", Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
myClass.getImg(img.getNativeObjAddr())
```

My Native Code:

```
JNIEXPORT jfloat JNICALL Java_PredictJNI_getImg
(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jlong imgPtr)
{
    CvMat* img = (CvMat*)imgPtr;
    printf("Image Width:%d:" , img->cols);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So don't pass whole `Mat` structure. Pass just pointer to raw data instead.

```
//uchar* ptr2imgData = dynamic_cast<uchar *>( imgPtr );
//cv::Mat img( cv::Size{ WIDTH, HEIGHT }, CV_8UC3, ptr2imgData ); // C++

uchar* ptr2imgData = (uchar *)imgPtr;  // uchar is unsigned char
CvMat* img = cvCreateMat( WIDTH, HEIGHT, CV_8UC3 );
img->ptr = imgPtr;
```

If type of matrix and/or matrix size may differ, pass additional info in another argument(s). If type of matrix is always the same, leave it hardcoded and pass just pointer to data.

Then construct new `Mat` from these data.

I have never written line of Java and I'm proud of it - anyway I know there are no pointers. I found you may use `get()` method

```
myClass.getImg(img.get(0, 0)); // Beginning of the array
```

or your mentioned `getNativeObjAddr()` method

```
myClass.getImg(img.getNativeObjAddr());
```

---

Your solution can't work and invokes undefined behavior, because `cvMat` and `Mat` are totally different types.

Comment: Dear Filip. Your help would be appreciable. I finally could reconstruct my CvMat object. but there is  yet another problem. as far as you mention that, java doesn't have any pointer and I have to send all my array to my native function. the function img.get(0,0) returns an array of doubles in java. the only pointer I have is img.getNativeObjAddr(). do you have any idea to solve ?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not expert on Java. You might want to ask another question with reference to this and ask how to get required pointer. I think it doesnt matter whether its pointer do double, you just need address of array in memory. Does `img.get(0, 0);` or `img.getNativeObjAddr()` work ? If not, whats the problem ? Is there any error code / message you may provide ?

Comment: Actually there is no error code, the performance is my problem. img.get(0, 0) returns array and I have to send an array to my native code(not a pointer to array). so it puts an heavy loading process on my memory.

Comment: Since Java has **no pointers** and is **pass-by-value** this is the only solution according to me (but as I said, I'm not expert). Maybe try to pass first element and see what happens ? `myClass.getImg(img.get(0, 0)[0]);`

Comment: If the question is solved, please, feel free to mark answer as accepted. Otherwise feel free to ask whats wrong.